# Access SQL JOIN with subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery

Can someone tell me how I can convert this query to work in MS Access?

```
SELECT Shooters.idShooters, Shooters.firstname, Shooters.lastname, JoinedContingent.Count, JoinedShots.Count 
FROM Shooters 
INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT Shooters.idShooters, Count(Contingent.idContingent) AS Count
           FROM Shooters LEFT JOIN Contingent ON Shooters.idShooters = Contingent.fidShooter
           GROUP BY Shooters.idShooters) 
AS JoinedContingent ON JoinedContingent.idShooters = Shooters.idShooters 
INNER JOIN 
          (SELECT Shooters.idShooters, Count(Shots.idShots) AS Count
           FROM Shooters LEFT JOIN Shots ON Shooters.idShooters = Shots.fidShooters
           GROUP BY Shooters.idShooters) 
AS JoinedShots ON JoinedShots.idShooters = Shooters.idShooters;
```

---

### Background information:

I would like to count the foreign key occurrences for each `Shooter` in the table `Contingent` and `Shots`. The result should look like this:

```
  idShooters  |  firstname  |  lastname  |  Count  | Count
____________________________________________________________
      1            John          Doe          0       10
      2            Jane          Doe          1       20
      .
      .
      .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT s.idShooters, s.firstname, s.lastname,
        NZ(c.Count, 0), NZ(sh.Count, 0)
FROM (Shooters as s LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT c.fidShooter, Count(*) AS Count
       FROM Contingent as c
       GROUP BY c.fidShooter
      ) as c
      ON s.idShooters = c.fidShooter
     ) LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT sh.fidShooters, Count(*) AS Count
      FROM Shots as sh
      GROUP BY sh.fidShooters 
     ) as sh
     ON s.idShooters = sh.fidShooters;
```

Note that I moved the outer join to the *outer* query.  Actually, no joins are needed in the subqueries, so don't bother.

Comment: Thank you so much it works perfect. I was about to give up because I am not familiar with this special Access syntax.